# line strikethrough is not show in middle of UILabel swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring, strikethrough

I have assigned `attributedText` to `UILabel` see the following code, But strike through line is not displayed center (vertically/meddle) of UIlabel text.

[image]

```
let strikethroughAttribute = [
        .font: UIFont(name: "Roboto-Medium", size: 16.0)!,
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.gray,
        .strikethroughStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
        .strikethroughColor: UIColor.gray] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]
}

var formattedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "$198")
formattedString.addAttributes(strikethroughAttribute, range: NSMakeRange(0, formattedString.length))

label.attributedText = formattedString
```

Comment: Depending on the font you're using, this would change.

Comment: It is not depending on font i have tested with UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0), But not shown properly .

Comment: Seems to be default behavior. I just typed $198 in PowerPoint on Windows using a different font, and see exactly the same.